# Passing in form field value to PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'd like to do a dynamic search function using jQuery and PHP.
I'm struggling passing the HTML form field to the JQUERY function (which would then get passed to the PHP file).

My major questions are:

1) How do I pass form "Input" field into Jquery function?

2) How do I get the PHP result in the form "Output" field?

I currently have... (simplified)

```
JQUERY:
$.get("SEARCH.php", {"_input" :  $('input[name=input]').val()},
function(returned_data) 
{
   $("input[name=output]").val(returned_data);
}


SEARCH.php:
$input = 'Welcome ' . $_GET['_input'];
echo $input;
//should be "Welcome" plus whatever I type in to "input"



HTML FORM:
input: <input type="text" name="input" value="" /> 
output: <input type="text" name="output" id="output" />
```

Thank you!

Comment: @RobinMaben lol Robin... oops.

Comment: search how to use jquery selectors, `$(selector)`, `$(selector).val(value)` etc

Comment: Maybe give jquery UI [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) a try? I don't know if this will meet your requirements but looking at example I think that it can be usefull.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**jQuery**

```
$.get("SEARCH.php", {"_input" : $('input[name=input]').val() },
function(returned_data) {
   $("input[name=output]").val( returned_data );
}
```

**HTML**

```
input: <input type="text" name="input" value="" />
output: <input type="text" name="output" />
```

**PHP**  Use `echo` instead of `return` since it looks that your code isn't in function:

```
$input = $_GET['_input'];
do some parsing of the input
echo $result;
```

Comment: Is the request being sent? can you see it in Firebug?

Comment: It works, but doesn't auto-update the server like AJAX should do. It's only when I refresh the page that it reflects the input.

Comment: try `function(returned_data) { alert( returned_data ); }` instead of changing the input value - just to see if it really works

Comment: Yes, it welcomes me, but that's only when I load the page or refresh. It won't alert me if I type anything into the input, which tells me that the javascript is working, but not the jquery as it should.

Comment: how do you fire the submit? do you have a submit button?

Comment: Do I have to call the javascript function through the form field? I was doing that before when working with the XMLHTTPRequest using onkeyup="javascript function(this.value)", but now it seems like jquery's callback is already calling the javascript function.

Comment: Okay I figured it out... Needed to actually call the function using an event listener on the html form.  Form: onkeyup="showHint(this.value),   Script: $(document).ready(function showHint() { }...

Answer (score 3):

***jQuery***

```
$.get("SEARCH.php", {"_input" : $('input[name=input]').val() },
function(returned_data) {
    $('#output').val(returned_data);
});
```

***PHP***

```
$input = $_GET['_input'];
do some parsing of the input
echo $result; // not return
```

***HTML***

```
input: <input type="text" name="input" value="" />
output: <input type="text" name="result" id="output" value="" />
```